# WooCommerce, disable shipping based on an acf field

Tags: woocommerce

I added a true/false field inside the user profile through acf.

I need to hide a specific shipment if this field is selected or not.

If selected, the shipment must be hidden.

This is my code:

```
function filter_woocommerce_package_rates( $rates, $package ) {
   
$user_id = get_current_user_id();
$verified=false;
$acf_field=get_user_meta( $user_id, 'fast_shipping', true );
   
    if($acf_field) $verified=true;
   
// Loop trough
foreach ( $rates as $rate_id => $rate ) {
   
    if ( $verified ) {
        unset( $rates['flat_rate:8'] );
    }
}  
return $rates;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_package_rates', 'filter_woocommerce_package_rates', 10, 2 );
```

But nothing is hidden.

Comment: First of all, you should check/print $acf_field, because if you got nothing in that case $verified  always return false and  then  unset( $rates['flat_rate:8'] ); will not work if  $verified = false;  refrence URL is - https://www.businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-hide-shipping-options-free-shipping-available/

Comment: The problem is that it prints empty because I put this flag inside the user in the dashboard, but then if I try to buy from not logged in (guest), the value prints nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try below code:

```
function filter_woocommerce_package_rates( $rates, $package ) {
   
$user_id = get_current_user_id();
$verified=false;
$acf_field=get_user_meta( $user_id, 'fast_shipping', true );
   
    if(is_bool($acf_field) == 1) $verified=true;
   
    if ( is_bool($verified) == 1 ) {
        unset( $rates['flat_rate:8'] );
    }

return $rates;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_package_rates', 'filter_woocommerce_package_rates', 10, 2 );
```

Please let me know if you find any issues.

Comment: It works. But if I then try to remove the flag from the user to test no longer performs the check even if I clean user sessions from WooCommerce.

Comment: Let me check it

Comment: Please try again the above edited answer code

Comment: The problem is that it does not see the field if it is 1 or 0 buying as a guest. Obviously if you are logged in it can understand the field associated with the user. How can that be fixed?

Comment: For the guest user it can be set or unset without any match cases. You can add the code if not logged in then allow shipping or not to allow shipping.

Comment: If you find trouble to add the code for guest user to set or unset the shipping. please let me know.